# GPS signal lost warning notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

Can anyone tell how to show an error message when GPS signal is not available on iphone.
And the lat,lon label remains shows the previous reading where the signal is lost. Please anyone guide me.

Thanks prior.....

Answer (score 4):

Implement the [CLLocationManagerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html) protocol method `locationManager:didFailWithError:`.

Here's a quote from the documentation:

> **Discussion**
>
> Implementation of this
>   method is optional. You should
>   implement this method, however.
>
> If the location service is unable to
>   retrieve a location fix right away, it
>   reports a [kCLErrorLocationUnknown](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationConstantsRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kCLErrorLocationUnknown)
>   error and keeps trying. In such a
>   situation, you can simply ignore the
>   error and wait for a new event.

To keep the values you should buffer them in a property and only update them when `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` fires.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could happen, when having and then losing "true" GPS, is that Core Location will fall back to cell tower triangulation or wifi sniffing.

The only way you'd know that had happened is a sudden increase in the `.horizontalAccuracy` value of the `CLLocation` objects you get in your `didUpdateToLocation:` method.